# How to get landing gear to properly stick?

Tags: space-engineers

So I just got Space Engineers today and so far it's turned out to be almost on par with Kerbal Space Program. (In different ways)

However, I got the Rescue Ship and a basic station, and tried to land the thing, I maneuver it, settle it down, and the landing gear glows meaning it's attached, but it's so weak, if I touch the ship it just floats off...

Is there anyway I can make it **stick** like glue? And have to forcefully push up or turn off my gear altogether to make it un-stick?

I'm still very new to this experience, so any help whatsoever will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that on multiplayer servers, sometimes the Landing Gear can somehow unstick by itself. Reason currently unknown. On my private server I found a workaround to use a landing gear from the ship sticking in the base, and build another on the base fixing the ship unto it.

Comment: @HugoRocha Thanks for the advice. I've only played SP so far though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is worth noting that you cannot have landing gear being locked AND also being locked to a connector at the same time.

A possible solution that worked for me was provided by [Yellow Claw here](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198066581540/posthistory/):

1. Create landing gear; completely build it.
2. Save and reload your save.
3. Build cockpit and enter it; and then press "P" so it sticks to
   the ground.
4. And then continue building like normal

Also the glowing does not nessecarily indicate that the landing gear is correctly positioned.

Taken from the [space engineers wiki](http://spaceengineers.wikia.com/wiki/Landing_Gear):

- **Yellow** - The landing gear is not engaged, but is within range of a
  suitable surface to attach itself to.
- **Blue** - The gear is in auto
  locking mode and will lock as soon as a mass is in range.
- **Green** - The
  gear is connected to a surface and secured.
- **Black** - The gear is not
  within range of a suitable surface.

Comment: Taken from the **wiki** not the **wikipedia**. Wikipedia is a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki), but not every wiki is [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia).

Comment: You all did good answers which were practically the same, but it's only fair to give the oldest one a tick. xD Thanks. My gears always been yellow... Unless I'm building on a surface, so thanks for that. Will press P next time. :P

Answer (score 2):

What color is your landing gear glowing in?

When it is glowing **yellow**, it is in range of a surface to attach to, but not actually attached. Press `P` to attach it to the surface. A landing gear which is attached will glow **green**.

You can also but the landing gear in "auto-lock" mode. It will then attach to the first available surface. When in auto-lock mode, the landing gear glows **light-blue**.

Answer (score 1):

The landing gear should have a "Breaking Force" variable in the control panel, double check that yours is set to unlimited.  However, from what I have seen even unlimited breaking force will be broken if there is sufficient force (which I suppose makes the name a misnomer), especially if you collide another ship with it or put it in the "hangar" of a larger ship which then accelerates.

To add some extra protection, you can make your landing pad out of large landing gears on the station or large ship you are landing on, and lock those, though if you use auto-lock your small ship will actually stop a few feet above the gear and its own landing gear won't engage (but it will be locked in by the large landing gear).  YMMV using this on a moving large ship though.